# createTextFinder on another sheet getting wrong find

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using createTextFinder to search a different sheet than active and remove the row base off timeStamp. The row its deleting is the wrong row most of the time. I can't tell what the pattern is.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-CgI_MigmgKBwFqA5ZhUzuTrmpLI-6emZg4FDuFwjfo/edit?usp=sharing
There's a master "Actions" list that splits off into locations sheets. When the checkbox on "E" in actions is checked the Location "G" lists should delete the row found by createTextFinder with the timeStamp in "A".

```
 if (src.getName() != "Actions" || r.columnStart != 5 || r.rowStart == 1 || !r.isChecked()) return;
 const timeStamp = r.offset(0, -4).getDisplayValue();
 const dest = e.source.getSheetByName(r.offset(0, 2).getValue());
//  const find = dest.getRange("A3:A" + dest.getLastRow()).createTextFinder(timeStamp).findNext();
 const find = dest.createTextFinder(timeStamp).findNext();
...
 if (!find) return;
  dest.deleteRow(find.getRow());
```

I also have a problem now where I can't run checkbox code if it doesn't have a location selected.

Comment: When I saw your provided Spreadsheet, I found 9 sheets and Google Apps Script project including 5 functions. In your question, can I ask you about the detail of the relationship between these 9 sheets and 5 functions and your showing script and your question? Because I thought that your showing script works for your expected situation. So, first, I thought that I would like to correctly understand your question. I apologize for this.

Comment: After some testing I found it has to do with the timeStamp. .getDisplayValue(); does not work with .setValue(new Date()); at the time level. My hope was createTextFinder(timeStamp).findNext(); was seeing the time value to find an exact timestamp incase something has the same date, which it is deleting the first row with the same date. Is there a way to get the time that is associated?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your reply. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: Ok I'm guessing the time in the date cells can't be used to createTextFinder() the time because its not actually displayed, the text at the top shows the time but not the cell.

Comment: Thank you for replying. What does `the text at the top shows the time but not the cell.` mean? I cannot understand it. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill. For example, do you want to search the empty cells?

Comment: Using '.setValue(new Date());' on a cell displays a date in the the cell but not the time. The top text bar(I don't know what to call it) shows the date and time. '.getValue()' gives date and time, '.getDisplayValue()' gives just the date no time, when I see their values.

Comment: On top of that I think '.createTextFinder()' seems to grab the DisplayValue of a Date() cell, so I believe the next best option is to display the time in the cell like it shows in the top text bar.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `Using '.setValue(new Date());' on a cell displays a date in the the cell but not the time.`, where can I see `.setValue(new Date());` in your question? I'm worried that I might be seeing a different question from your situation. How about this? So, I'm confused. I think that this is due to my poor English skill. I apologize for this.

Comment: I deeply apologize for my poor English skill, again. I think that when I could correctly understand questions, I think that I will be able to think of solutions. But, in many cases, I cannot understand the questions. For this reason, I cannot think of solutions to questions. About this situation, I have to continue to apologize for my poor English skill. I think that I have to study English more.